# Curve TextBlock in Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I want to create Curved TextBlock using XAML like:

[image]

I am doing it like this :

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" FontSize="30" Height="46"
           Width="182" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Foreground="White"
           Margin="486,125,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
    <TextBlock.Projection>
        <PlaneProjection RotationZ="360" />
    </TextBlock.Projection>
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-30"/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

But no success.
Can you tell me a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to work on converting this to Windows 8:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30090/Text-On-A-Path-in-WPF

Comment: @user3116366 Did you manage to convert the WPF example?
How did you manage to get methods like GetFlattenedPathGeometry() in WinRT?

Comment: I said try, I didn't invest time to convert to WPF but thought was possible