# Curve Texblock in XAML / W8.1 throughTemplate?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is it possible to access the TextBlock Template to change the border and make it curved?
I tried editing the Template through Blend but with no success.

I'm trying to achieve something like this (couldn't get that given solution working):
[Curve TextBlock in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017542/curve-textblock-in-windows-8)

I'm trying to do this in C#/XAML - WINRT (Windows 8.1)

Comment: I don't think there's a default ability in RT for LayoutPath but there are a couple types of [options](http://studentguru.gr/b/kaisaras89/archive/2013/02/23/enabling-an-element-to-animate-on-a-path-on-windows-8-store-apps-i-e-making-a-pathlistbox-layoutpath-for-windows-rt) out there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a `TextBlock` has a template you could modify. It's probably just some parameters used to tell DirectWrite what text to render and with what properties. The easiest way to solve it is when your text is constant to just break it apart into multiple single letter `TextBlocks` and lay them out on a path using Blend or Illustrator. If don't control what text can show up on the path - you'd have to code up the layout algorithm. Chris's link seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clean way to do this directly in Xaml. Like Filip says, you can approach it by breaking the letters apart. That can work well for long sentences with small letters, but can be pretty chunky with large or connected letters. If you need smoother rendering then you can [interop to Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh825871.aspx).

MSDN has a [Direct2D animated text on a path](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Animating-Text-on-a-Path-883382a0) sample which you could combine with [the XAML SurfaceImageSource DirectX interop sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SurfaceImageSource-58f7e4d5)